# how can I exclude ddl excution in liquibase

Tags: liquibase, ddl, restrict

I have a problem, I need exclude ddl execution in liquibase but I do not how I can do.

I did to laboratory in maven with java but it dones't work in this case with is liquibase normal therefore I expecting some that it can help me.

Comment: you can use [label or context](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/contexts-vs-labels)

Comment: can you give me an example? because I still don't understand.

Comment: well mark your DDL changelogs with `label|context` `DDL` and others with `DATA` for example. Then when you want to execute only `DDL` you will pass something like `label=DDL` and it should execute only `DDL`. And if I remeber correctly, when you won't pass any context or label it executes everything.